# Apply layout arguments set by \geometry (geometry) to \includepdf[ (pdfpages)

Tags: geometry, pdfpages, layout

I am a newcomer to LaTeX and have already produced a few documents with satisfactory quality for me. Now I have decided to write my thesis in LaTeX. For this purpose, I use a template from Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl) for my thesis. This template defines several layout argument via \geometry:

```
\geometry{
paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
top=1.5cm, % Top margin
bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
%showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}
```

I am currently trying to include multi-page pdf-files in the document, which also works.

```
\includepdf[pages={1-}]{example.pdf}
```

However, the pdfs do not take over the arguments initially defined by \geometry like the normal text body. Instead, the embedded pdfs are centered.

I have already searched for forum posts and played around with various arguments, but have not found a solution to my problem. Does anyone know how I can adopt the layout for the embedded pdfs?

Edit: Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1-}]{example.pdf}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have now found out that the geometry arguments for "inner", "outer", "top", "bottom" can be controlled via the pdfpages argument "offset" (with 2 parameters). In my case I use the double-sided option for my document. In this case the first "offset" parameter represents the shift to "outer" and the second to "top" direction. As I see it, pdfpages only allows one parameter to be selected for the horizontal spacing for a two-sided document. In template, however, unequal distances for the right and left margins are defined for the geometry. In addition, the "bindingoffset" argument from geometry adds a specified length to the inner margin for binding purpose. Do I understand correctly that the geometry format of a twosided document cannot be transferred to pdfpages? If so, does anyone know of an alternative to pdfpages that can do this?

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm still trying to apply the geometry arguments to the pasted PDF, but I still can't find a solution.  Doesn't anyone really have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please always provide full but minimal examples not sniplets taken out of context. It is much easier to help when we have a full self contains example we can just copy and test as is.

Comment: do not search in forum posts: search the documentation of pdfpages. It explains quite well all the option to scale and place the pdfs.

Comment: One way to apply different offsets on even/odd pages is to simply include each page of the pdf with a separate command, since pdfpages allows you to define which pages of the document you insert.